# SQL group by/groups

Tags: php, sql

I have this in my table : Challenge1 :

```
ID_GROUP     #     ID_TEAMS

1                  Chelsea
1                  Real Madrid
2                  MANU
2                  MANC
2                  TOT
3                  STOKE
3                  LIVERPOOL
```

ANd I want to display this on my php page

```
GROUP 1

Chelsea
Real Madrid

Group 2

MANU
MANC
TOT
```

When I made this :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM challenge1 GROUP BY id_group";
```

It isn't correct because it select me only Chelsea but not Real Madrid in the Group 1.. Can you help me please ? thank you

Comment: just select *, and then probably in your php you can do if group == 1 place the team name here, if group = 2 place the team name here.  Or write seperat queries, for group 1 select * from blah where group = 1

Comment: OK but there isn't a request that made the all work ?

Comment: GROUP BY is used to return one row per group. This is not what you want. Use ORDER BY id_group instead and handle the group heading logic in php code.

Comment: Your `group by` usage is invalid SQL and would have been rejected by every other DBMS - MySQL chooses to return "random" data instead. Read this for more details: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comment of user1336827 are solutions.

If you are using MYSQL then the next one is used [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Your sql will be then:

```
$sql = "SELECT id_group,group_concat(ID_TEAMS) as list_of_teams FROM challenge1 GROUP BY id_group";
```

Comment: GOOD! But when I made an echo, it show me that : 1,2. I want that I show me that separetely you understand? @Casero

Comment: @user3149518 php's explode() function to split list_of_teams using delimiter ','

Comment: Ok I made this ! thanks a lot !